# What is different between 5.4.0-59 and 5.4.59 kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am in a trouble because of lack of understanding related with kernel version.

The following page shows a lot of kernel version

http://files.trendmicro.com/documentation/guides/deep_security/Kernel%20Support/11.0/Deep_Security_11_kernels_EN.html#ubuntu

But I can't find the 5.4.0-59 version from the mainline page.

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.59/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.59/)

Is 5.4.0-59 and 5.4.59 same?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: They are (probably) not the same. For example, Debian's 5.9.0-5 kernels are based on the mainline 5.9.15 kernel. And Ubuntu's 5.4.0-59-generic kernel is based on the mainline 5.4.78 kernel.